# Why is there no * in this method declaration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, ios

Here is the method declaration midway in Apple's documentation:
[Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594)

```
- (void)insertObject:(id) anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger) index
```

Why is there no `*` right after `NSUInteger`. I thought all objects were pointer types and all strongly typed pointers had to have a `*` character after it.

Comment: Don't confuse NSInteger/NSUInteger with NSNumber. NSInteger is (roughly) equivalent to CFIndex/ssize_t and NSUInteger is (roughly) equivalent to size_t. I'm not sure why they don't just use standard types, but there you go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSUInteger` is not an object type, it is a `typedef` to `unsigned int`.

The only reason that you would actually want to use a `*` in this context would be if you wanted to get the address of an int and store something in it. (Some libraries do this with error messaging). An example of this:

```
-(void) methodName: (NSUInteger *) anInt {
    *anInt = 5;
}

NSUInteger a;
[obj methodName: &a]; //a is now 5
```

Comment: Two errors: NSInteger/NSUInteger/CFindex are 64-bit types on 64-bit systems, since they're used to represent stuff like lengths/counts/offsets of stuff in memory. Also, you mean *anInt = 5.

Comment: I think the line `NSUInteger *a` is wrong, it should be without the `*`. As it stands, you end up with a local variable of pointer type (and whose value is unspecified), and in the line below you apply the `&` operator on this local variable, giving an expression which is a pointer to a pointer to something. This is different from what your method expects, namely just a pointer.

Comment: @harms, you are right. It was either defining it as a pointer and passing it directly or defining it normally and using the `&` (address-of) operator.